# How to mavenize junit testsuite in which testcases are added dynamically?

Tags: maven

I have a TestSuite in which both testsuites and testcases need to be added dynamically. 
The following link explains how it is done -
http://jorgemanrubia.net/2008/09/18/generating-junit-test-cases-dynamically/

Now I need to mavenize this and run the tests via maven build, I tried using the @RunWith(AllTest.class) annotation but still it fails saying no tests found.

Any clues or help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html) has the ability to [add test source directories](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) to the project.  Once the test source directory is added, Maven will compile the tests and run them during the proper phases.  The plugin's [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) page has a good example of the needed plugin configuration.